# Hide WP plugin from front-end for logged-out users or visitors

Tags: css, wordpress

So I'm using a chat plugin for my WordPress site. I want to hide it on the front-end for visitors. There is no setting for that in the plugin itself. I think using CSS for that purpose would be great. Like using the class for WP visitors and add:

`display: none;`

How do I do it? Is there any plugin or code available for non-logged-in user specific stylesheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this is by adding a shortcode which checks for only logged in users.

Add the following in your child theme's functions.php

```
add_shortcode( 'member', 'member_check_shortcode' );

function member_check_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
     if ( is_user_logged_in() && !is_null( $content ) && !is_feed() )
     return $content;
     return '';
}
```

The above code will add a shortcode that you can use for only logged in users. Now you can put the code of the plugin like so:

```
[member]
Plugin Code
[/member]
```

Or if you want to use it in a PHP file, you can do it like this:

```
echo do_shortcode( '[member]' . $text_to_be_wrapped_in_shortcode . '[/member]' );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the solution!